# Remove the tag "big-data"?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a [big-data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-data) tag with this description:

> Big data is one or more datasets that together are so large or complex as to require non-traditional techniques to understand.

The tagged questions actually do not match this description. Overall, the tag does not sounds very useful to me.

- Should we prevent its use?
- Should we improve its description to improve its use?

Comment: I vote to remove the tag, especially for questions about "big" csv files.

Comment: I am a new entry, but "big data" is a keyword in IEEE conferences. When we talk about big data we think about Google, Facebook, StackExchange, and all big masses of data which are impossible to process with desktop programs, like Excel, Access and similar. Look [here](https://scholar.google.it/scholar?q=big+data) for more details.

Comment: I start as dba and I think that, used properly, it is useful. I vote to keep it.